# Any known translations of the Talmudim et al into classical languages, prior to the 19th century?

Tags: translation, talmud-bavli, talmud-yerushalmi

Through the 19th and 20th centuries, the Bavli and Yerushalmi were fully or partially translated into English, French, German, Arabic and Italian.

Are there any extant translations of the Talmudim and/or other rabbinic texts (e.g., midrashim, hiddushim, codes, mussar, etc) of the early period (say, made c. 200 - 1000 C.E.) into any of the classical languages (Greek, Latin, Arabic, Persian)? The translations can have been made at any time between 200 and 1800 C.E.

It is well known that portions of the Bavli were translated into Latin during the 13th century as part of the Jewish-Christian disputations in Paris. The manuscripts were recently published by Cecini and de la Cruz Palma (*Extractiones de Talmud per ordinem sequentialem*, 2019).

Apparently there was an Arabic translation made in the 11th century by Yosef  ibn Abitur by commission of an Islamic ruler, but I'm not aware of any extant copies.

Does anyone know of anything else?

.

(By means of comparison, the Quran was first translated into Persian in the 7th century, into Greek during the 9th century, citations of which still remain from Nicetas of Byzantium, and into three or four Latin translations in the medieval period.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Most if not all of the translations below include detailed notes that cite many other Rabbinical works.

(It must be noted that the purposes of the translations and commentaries listed below varied widely. Some of the authors were [humanists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Renaissance_humanism) interested in classicism, comparative religion and jurisprudence, and the like; others, some of who were apostates, had anti-Semitic and/or missionizing agendas.)

### Mishnah

**Latin:**

- Pirkei Avot ([Isny im Allgäu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isny_im_Allg%C3%A4u), 1541) – [Bavarian State Library](https://daten.digitale-sammlungen.de/0002/bsb00021989/images/index.html?id=00021989&&seite=13) <sup>[Kb](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/15256)</sup>
- [Sanhedrin and Makkos](https://catalog.loc.gov/vwebv/holdingsInfo?searchId=8612&recCount=25&recPointer=1&bibId=8409937) (Amsterdam, 1629) – [Google Books](https://books.google.com/books?id=VgVcAAAAQAAJ) <sup>[ba](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/1569)</sup>
- [Middos](https://catalog.loc.gov/vwebv/holdingsInfo?searchId=9179&recCount=25&recPointer=9&bibId=8273294) (Leiden, 1630) – [Google Books](https://books.google.com/books?id=4H4CAAAAYAAJ) <sup>[M](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/18471)</sup>
- [Bava Kamma](https://catalog.loc.gov/vwebv/holdingsInfo?searchId=8657&recCount=25&recPointer=89&bibId=10146528) (Leiden, 1637) – [Google Books](https://books.google.hu/books?id=bQVHAAAAcAAJ). The Library of Congress has a copy that was previously in Thomas Jefferson's library, and [it has his initials in a couple of places](https://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/baba-kamma-judaic-treasures). <sup>[M](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/18471)</sup>
- Yoma (London, 1648) – [Google Books](https://books.google.com/books?id=yLljAAAAcAAJ) <sup>[Kb](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/15256)</sup>
- Avot deRabbi Natan (London, 1654) – [Google Books](https://books.google.com/books?id=SvQNAAAAYAAJ) <sup>[Kb](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/15256)</sup>
- Sotah ([Altdorf bei Nürnberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/University_of_Altdorf), 1674) – [Google Books](https://books.google.com/books?id=tJRCAAAAcAAJ) <sup>[Kb](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/15256)</sup>
- Avodah Zarah and Tamid (Altdorf bei Nürnberg, 1680) – [Google Books](https://books.google.com/books?id=wDI_AAAAcAAJ) <sup>[Kb](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/15256)</sup>
- [Rosh Hashanah and Sanhedrin](https://catalog.loc.gov/vwebv/holdingsInfo?searchId=9208&recCount=25&recPointer=6&bibId=6069045) (Amsterdam, 1695) – [Google Books](https://books.google.hu/books?id=yM7_IV1iREQC) <sup>[M](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/18471)</sup>
- Taanit ([Helmstedt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/University_of_Helmstedt), 1712) – [Google Books](https://books.google.hu/books?id=J5NAAAAAcAAJ) <sup>[Kb](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/15256)</sup>

A full Mishnayot edition, including the commentaries of the Rambam and Bartenura, was translated by [Willem Surenhuis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Willem_Surenhuis) and printed by Gerardus and Jacobus Borstius:

- Zeraim (Amsterdam, 1698) – [Google Books](https://books.google.hu/books?id=hXNgAAAAcAAJ) <sup>[Kb](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/15256)</sup>
- Moed (Amsterdam, 1699) – [Google Books](https://books.google.hu/books?id=NVE_AAAAcAAJ) <sup>[Kb](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/15256)</sup>
- Nashim (Amsterdam, 1700) – [Google Books](https://books.google.hu/books?id=sGgN2tUwldQC) <sup>[Kb](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/15256)</sup>
- Nezikin (Amsterdam, 1702) – [Google Books](https://books.google.hu/books?id=YVE_AAAAcAAJ) <sup>[Kb](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/15256)</sup>
- Kodashim (Amsterdam, 1702) – [Google Books](https://books.google.hu/books?id=F3FgAAAAcAAJ) <sup>[Kb](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/15256)</sup>
- Taharot (Amsterdam, 1703) – [Google Books](https://books.google.hu/books?id=_kfb4S0IlhYC) <sup>[Kb](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/15256)</sup>

**English:**

- Shabbat and Eruvin (London, 1718) – [few pages](https://www.nli.org.il/en/books/NNL_ALEPH001198455) [available](https://www.kedem-auctions.com/product/shabbath-and-eruvin-tractates-%E2%80%93-london-1718-%E2%80%93-english-%E2%80%93-two-volumes/) [online](http://onthemainline.blogspot.com/2006/03/william-wottons-english-mishnayos-i.html) <sup>[Kb](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/15256)</sup>

### Gemara

**Latin:**

- Mishnah with selections from Talmud (Sanhedrin, Berachot), and part of Rambam's introduction to Mishnah (1519, by [Paolo Riccio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paolo_Riccio)) - [Google Books](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=TBY8AAAAcAAJ&hl=iw&pg=PP5#v=onepage&q&f=false) <sup>[ba](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/1569/b-a)</sup>
- Chagigah: 11b-16a (2:1) (Leiden, 1704 – translated by [Johann Heinrich Hottinger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johann_Heinrich_Hottinger), published by [Jordaan Luchtmans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brill_Publishers#Luchtmans%2C_1683%E2%80%931848)) – [Google Books](https://books.google.hu/books?id=PpZCAAAAcAAJ) <sup>[Kb](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/15256)</sup>

**Dutch:**

- Berakhot: selected parts without the original text (Amsterdam, 1737 – translated by [Jacob Fundam](https://www.jstor.org/stable/41482398), published by Arent van Huyssteen) – [Google Books](https://books.google.hu/books?id=XYVeAAAAcAAJ) <sup>[Kb](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/15256)</sup>

Comment: @Kazibácsi Wow. I'll make the answer a community wiki, so you (and others) can add your findings.

Comment: @Kazibácsi True. But then again, I shouldn't be getting more points for the value you add to an answer, now, should I?

Comment: Honestly, I hadn't been aware of these translations, and when you started to list them, I also started to look them up in a few places I know, so why not? :-)

Comment: @Kazibácsi It's funny how these things work. I started out knowing only about the Bava Kamma translation (from a recollection of an old post on mail-jewish), then in searching for it found another three, and now you've added so many more. I think this is a shining example of how collaboration and the Internet enable us to learn in a way we never could have before.